# CSHTML com tabs está deixando uma linha horizontal no final da página

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc-5, twitter-bootstrap

Tenho uma página com 4 tabs. Está funcionando. Acontece que tenho uma div para cada tab. O fim da tab e início da outra fica assim:

```
.....
</div>
</form>
</div>
<div id=tabs-2>
.....
```

Ao final da div antes do  fica uma linha horizontal de ponta a ponta, e se eu colocar qualquer coisa após essa div e antes de terminar o form, a linha divide os controles. Já tentei de várias formas retirar essa linha e não consegui. O que devo fazer?

Comment: Você chegou a inspecionar o elemento no browser pra ver qual parte do CSS está colocando essa linha?

Comment: Pode postar um jsFiddle?

Comment: Resolvido nesse link:

http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/22654/problemas-com-a-apresenta%C3%A7%C3%A3o-do-cshtmlvisual

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A resolução desse post foi feita dessa forma:

```
<div id="tabs" style="border:none">
```